# MYSQL Data Disorganized After Express.js HTML form submission

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, web-applications

I can get data to submit (POST) into MYSQL w/ Express, but the data does not appear in one  single column in the query grid but the form submission data is in numerous columns making me think it is disorganized and will make future retrievals difficult.  Please let me know what is off in my node.js code.   The front end is rendered by express using pug(EJS templates) rather than pure html.  Please lmk if you need different code snippets and how I can keep the data organized.   Thank You.

```
//Q1
var firstname = req.body.firstname;
connection.query("INSERT INTO `Questions` (firstname) VALUES (?)", firstname.toString(), function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Form submitted Q1");
})
//Q2
var lastname = req.body.lastname;
connection.query("INSERT INTO `Questions` (lastname) VALUES (?)", lastname.toString(), function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Form submitted Q2");
});
```

Comment: and why did you don't enter them at once, so you enter two rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enter both values at the same time, so that only one row gets inserted

```
  var users={

     "firstname":req.body.firstname,
     "lastname":req.body.lastname
   }
  
  connection.query('INSERT INTO `Questions` SET ?',users, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Form submitted Q1+Q2");
   });
```